# Ko Loadingwhen spinner Pointer events.

Tags: javascript, css, html, knockout.js, sass

I am a new bee to Knockout js. I recently encountered an issue with the loadingwhen custom binding handler, we are using a button Save to save the form and when the user hits save we trigger the loading spinner gif changes the display and make the button disabled. However, the issue is user was able to hit the spinner even when it is loading and the save function is called multiple times, no. of hits on the spinner -> no. of calls to save function and no. of duplicate records to the collection, have anyone faced this issue before, How can i resolve it.Could anyone please help me out with this issue. I really appreciate you time and help.
Thank you so much.

My code looks as below.
And also attaching an image of the result.

[image]

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.loadingWhen = {
 init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
  var $element = $(element);
  var currentPosition = $element.css('position');
  var loaderClass = ko.unwrap(allBindingsAccessor()).loaderClass || $element.attr('data-loader-class') || 'loader-white';
  var $loader = $('<span>', { 'class': loaderClass }).addClass('loader').hide();

  //add the loader
  $element.append($loader);

  //make sure that we can absolutely position the loader against the original element
  if (currentPosition === 'auto' || currentPosition === 'static') {
   $element.css('position', 'relative');
  }
 },
 update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
  var isLoading = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
  var $element = $(element);
  var $childrenToHide = $element.children(':not(span.loader)');
  var $loader = $element.find('span.loader');

  if (isLoading) {
   $childrenToHide.css('visibility', 'hidden').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $loader.stop(true, true).show();
  }
  else {
   $loader.fadeOut('fast');
   $childrenToHide.css('visibility', 'visible').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
 }
};


self.save = ko.command({

    action: function () {}
  })
  .done(function (data) {   
    alert('');
  })
```

```css
button() {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 48px; 
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;

  &.is-disabled,
  &[disabled] {
    color: $color-medium-gray;
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="button button-toolbar right" type="submit" data-bind="click: save, loadingWhen: save.isRunning, enable: validationModel.isValid " style="position: relative;">Save<span class="loader-white loader" style="display: none;"></span></button>
```

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS**.  Also, this question requires markup in order to reproduce the problem (see [MCVE]).

Answer (score 0):

So after some research and help of google developer tools I am able to figure out the issue and here is my fix, 
for me $element is a button and $element.children is empty object, so this $childrenToHide.css('visibility', 'hidden').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); is hiding the span but not disabling the spinner or disabling the button , I need to disable the button in order to trigger the css property .isdiabled. so i modified the update function as

```
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var isLoading = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    var $element = $(element);
    var $childrenToHide = $element.children(':not(span.loader)');
    var $loader = $element.find('span.loader');

    if (isLoading) {
        $childrenToHide.css('visibility', 'hidden').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $element.css('visibility', 'visible').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $loader.stop(true, true).show();
    }
    else {
        $loader.fadeOut('fast');
        $childrenToHide.css('visibility', 'visible').removeAttr('disabled');
        $element.css('visibility', 'visible').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
```

adding a css attr to disable parent button.
Thank you for checking this post, I hope this could help fellow developers. 
Cheers.